# Accessing Values In Matrix (Haskell Newbie)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, list, haskell

i am trying to do the equvilant of this in haskell bascially

```
for (int i = 0; i < city_Permutation_Route.length - 1; i++) {
        route_Distance = route_Distance + city_Distance_Matrix[city_Permutation_Route[i]][city_Permutation_Route[i + 1]];

    }
```

there i get the weight of each route, compare it against each of the others so that i print out the route with the lowest weighted route as follows

Route Weight = 453.4
Route = 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

i have functions to get the total route and all the other data but do not understand how to get values from the matrix

Question: How do i do this in haskell

i want to be able to get the values from my distance matrix using the permutation values as the index to it

Comment: Beware of `getperm [[]]`: this applies only to a list of length one, containing an empty list. Chances are this is not what you intended.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a permutation, for example `[3, 2, 7, 5, 4, 6, 0, 1]` you can compute all of the legs by [`zip`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:zip)ping it with its own [`tail`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:tail).

```
zip [3, 2, 7, 5, 4, 6, 0, 1]
    (tail [3, 2, 7, 5, 4, 6, 0, 1])

zip [3, 2, 7, 5, 4, 6, 0, 1]
    [2, 7, 5, 4, 6, 0, 1]

[(3,2),(2,7),(7,5),(5,4),(4,6),(6,0),(0,1)]
```

These are the indexes into the distance matrix for the cost of traveling between two points. If we look these up in the `city_Distance_Matrix` using the list indexing function [`!!`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:-33--33-) we get the cost for each leg

```
map (\(c0, c1) -> city_Distance_Matrix !! c0 !! c1)
    [(3,2),(2,7),(7,5),(5,4),(4,6),(6,0),(0,1)]

    [97.4, 71.6, 111.0,138.0,85.2 ,86.3 ,129.0]
```

If we total these, we get the total cost for traveling the legs of this permutation.

```
sum [97.4, 71.6, 111.0,138.0,85.2 ,86.3 ,129.0] = 718.5
```

Putting this all together, we can define a function that computes the total length of all the legs of a permutation of the cities. We can simplify the function by using [`zipWith`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:zipWith) which is a combination of `zip` and `map`.

```
totalLength :: [Int] -> Double
totalLength cities = sum $ zipWith (\c0 c1 -> city_Distance_Matrix !! c0 !! c1) cities (tail cities)
```

You should be able to use this to find the permutation whose `totalLength` is minimal.

Comment: thanks man i just look at the zip function and i totally understand now, i have done the functions for the sums and stuff but thanks for clarifying it for me. PS your a life saver i can now implement NN and RNN using the matrix look upthanks